# mapserverをmakeする過程で、Linking C executable sortshpにてエラーが発生します。

Tags: postgresql, cmake

こんにちは。以下の環境でmapserverをmakeしようとした際にエラーが発生し、解決できずに困っています。
アドバイスをお願いいたします。

■OS
CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)

■PostgreSQL

```
名前         : postgresql12-server
バージョン   : 12.3
リリース     : 5PGDG.rhel8
Arch         : x86_64
サイズ       : 20 M
ソース       : postgresql12-12.3-5PGDG.rhel8.src.rpm
リポジトリー : @System
repo から    : pgdg12
```

■PostGIS

```
名前         : postgis30_12
バージョン   : 3.0.1
リリース     : 5.rhel8
Arch         : x86_64
サイズ       : 33 M
ソース       : postgis30_12-3.0.1-5.rhel8.src.rpm
リポジトリー : @System
repo から    : pgdg12
```

その他、mapserverに必要なライブラリはすべてyumでインストール。

■GDAL

```
yum --enablerepo=epel,PowerTools install gdal gdal-devel
```

■PROJ

```
dnf install proj proj-devel
```

■libpng

```
dnf install libpng libpng-devel
```

■FreeType

```
yum -y install freetype freetype-devel
```

■libjpeg

```
yum -y install libjpeg libjpeg-devel
```

■zlib

```
yum -y install zlib zlib-devel
```

■libcurl

```
yum install libcurl libcurl-devel
```

■FRIBIDI

```
yum install fribidi fribidi-devel
```

■PROTOBUF

```
yum install protobuf protobuf-devel
```

■libtiff

```
yum install libtiff libtiff-devel
```

■GEOS

```
yum install --enablerepo=epel,PowerTools geos geos-devel
```

■libxml

```
yum install libxml2 libxml2-devel
```

■libgif

```
yum install giflib giflib-devel
```

■FastCGI

```
yum install fcgi fcgi-devel
```

■Cairo

```
yum install cairo cairo-devel
```

■XSLT

```
yum install libxslt libxslt-devel
```

■mapserverは次の通りcmakeでビルド。

```
tar xzvf mapserver-7.6.0.tar.gz
cd mapserver-7.6.0/
mkdir build
cd build

cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/pgsql-12/bin" -DWITH_PHP=ON -DWITH_CURL=ON -DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=ON -DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=ON -DWITH_KML=ON -DWITH_XMLMAPFILE=ON -DWITH_POSTGIS=ON -DWITH_PROTOBUFC=0 ..
```

■cmake結果

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Requiring C++11
-- Requiring C++11 - done
-- Requiring C99
-- Requiring C99 - done
-- Looking for strrstr
-- Looking for strrstr - not found
-- Looking for strcasecmp
-- Looking for strcasecmp - found
-- Looking for strcasestr
-- Looking for strcasestr - found
-- Looking for strlcat
-- Looking for strlcat - not found
-- Looking for strlcpy
-- Looking for strlcpy - not found
-- Looking for strlen
-- Looking for strlen - found
-- Looking for strncasecmp
-- Looking for strncasecmp - found
-- Looking for vsnprintf
-- Looking for vsnprintf - found
-- Looking for lrintf
-- Looking for lrintf - found
-- Looking for lrint
-- Looking for lrint - found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYNC_FETCH_AND_ADD
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYNC_FETCH_AND_ADD - Success
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib64/libz.so (found version "1.2.11")
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib64/libpng.so (found version "1.6.34")
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so
-- Found Freetype: /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so
-- Found PROJ: /usr/lib64/libproj.so
-- Found Proj 6.3
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "1.4.2")
-- Found FRIBIDI: /usr/lib64/libfribidi.so
-- Checking for module 'harfbuzz>=0.9.18'
--   Found harfbuzz, version 1.7.5
-- Found HarfBuzz: /usr/include/harfbuzz
-- Looking for iconv
-- Looking for iconv - found
-- Found iconv library:
-- Checking for module 'cairo'
--   Found cairo, version 1.15.12
-- Found CAIRO: /usr/lib64/libcairo.so
-- Found FCGI: /usr/lib64/libfcgi.so
-- Found GEOS: /usr/lib64/libgeos_c.so
-- Found POSTGRESQL: /usr/lib64/libpq.so
-- Looking for PQserverVersion in pq
-- Looking for PQserverVersion in pq - found
-- Found GDAL: /usr/lib64/libgdal.so
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib64/libcurl.so (found version "7.61.1")
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so (found version "2.9.7")
-- Found LibXslt: /usr/lib64/libxslt.so (found version "1.1.32")
-- Found GIF: /usr/lib64/libgif.so (found version "5.1.4")
-- /usr/include/php/main
-- Found PHP-Version 7.4.7 (using /usr/bin/php-config)
-- * Summary of configured options for this build
--  * Mandatory components
--   * GDAL: /usr/lib64/libgdal.so
--   * PROJ: /usr/lib64/libproj.so
--   * png: /usr/lib64/libpng.so
--   * jpeg: /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so
--   * freetype: /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so
--  * Optional components
--   * GIF: /usr/lib64/libgif.so
--   * MYSQL: disabled
--   * FRIBIDI: /usr/lib64/libfribidi.so
--   * HARFBUZZ: /usr/lib64/libharfbuzz.so
--   * GIF: /usr/lib64/libgif.so
--   * CAIRO: /usr/lib64/libcairo.so
--   * SVGCAIRO: disabled
--   * RSVG: disabled
--   * CURL: /usr/lib64/libcurl.so
--   * PIXMAN: disabled
--   * LIBXML2: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so
--   * POSTGIS: /usr/lib64/libpq.so
--   * GEOS: /usr/lib64/libgeos_c.so
--   * FastCGI: /usr/lib64/libfcgi.so
--   * PROTOBUFC: disabled
--   * Oracle Spatial: disabled
--   * Exempi XMP: disabled
--  * Optional features
--   * WMS SERVER: ENABLED
--   * WFS SERVER: ENABLED
--   * WCS SERVER: ENABLED
--   * SOS SERVER: disabled
--   * WMS CLIENT: ENABLED
--   * WFS CLIENT: ENABLED
--   * ICONV: ENABLED
--   * Thread-safety support: disabled
--   * KML output: ENABLED
--   * Z+M point coordinate support: ENABLED
--   * XML Mapfile support: ENABLED
--  * Mapscripts
--   * Python: disabled
--   * PHP: ENABLED
--   * PHPNG: disabled
--   * PERL: disabled
--   * RUBY: disabled
--   * JAVA: disabled
--   * C#: disabled
--   * V8 Javascript: disabled
--   * Apache Module (Experimental): disabled
--
-- PROJECT_BINARY_DIR is set to /root/mapserver-7.6.0/build
-- Will install files to /opt
-- Will install libraries to /opt/lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/mapserver-7.6.0/build
```

■makeを実行
`make`
■make結果(エラー部分抜粋)

```
[ 69%] Linking C executable sortshp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQcmdStatus@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQfname@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQsetNoticeProcessor@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQftable@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQstatus@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQftablecol@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQconnectdb@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQescapeStringConn@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `lo_close@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQputCopyEnd@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQgetvalue@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQgetisnull@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQftype@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQfmod@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `lo_creat@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQresultStatus@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `lo_read@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQexec@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQsetClientEncoding@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQgetlength@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQputCopyData@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQgetResult@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `lo_write@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQfinish@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQclear@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQerrorMessage@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQnfields@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `lo_open@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQexecParams@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQntuples@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libgdal.so: `PQresultErrorMessage@RHPG_9.6' に対する定義されていない参照です
collect2: エラー: ld はステータス 1 で終了しました
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sortshp.dir/build.make:101: sortshp] エラー 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/sortshp.dir/all] エラー 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] エラー 2
```

■試したこと
以下を参考にlibpqのパスを/usr/lib64だけを参照するようにしてみたが、解決ならず。
https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/issues/846

単純にmapserverをインストール完了まで持っていきたいのですが、うまくいきません…。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。pgdg-commonで提供されているgdal30と、geos38を利用する必要があったようです。
ついでに、protobufを有効にするにはprotobuf-cでした。

cmakeも少し変わって、

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt \
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/pgsql-12/bin;/usr/gdal30;/usr/geos38/lib64" \
    -DWITH_PHP=ON -DWITH_CURL=ON -DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=ON -DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=ON \
    -DWITH_KML=ON -DWITH_XMLMAPFILE=ON -DWITH_POSTGIS=ON -DWITH_PROTOBUFC=ON ..
```

お騒がせしました。